# Set different schema for different build types in Apollo v3 Android

Tags: android, build.gradle, apollo, apollo-client, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have 2 GraphQl schemas for debug and prod versions of my app. Also I have 2 build types: debug and release. Obviously, I want to use the debug-schema with the debug build-type, and the production-schema with the release one.

[According to this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/issues/2492#issuecomment-673414261), **Apollo v2** allows set such configuration using `onCompilationUnit`, and probably I can write smth like this:

```
apollo {
    onCompilationUnit {
        graphqlSourceDirectorySet.srcDirs += "src/main/graphql"
        def buildTypeName =(androidVariant as BaseVariant).buildType.name
        if (buildTypeName.contains('debug')) {
            graphqlSourceDirectorySet.srcDirs += "src/debug/graphql"
        } else if (buildTypeName.contains('release')) {
            graphqlSourceDirectorySet.srcDirs += "src/release/graphql"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I didn't find `onCompilationUnit` in **Apollo v3** (which is used in my project).

The main question is: How to configure gradle to force **Apollo v3** use different schemas for different build-types?
I think analogue of `onCompilationUnit` in **Apollo v3** will resolve this question. Please suggest me one if it exists in **Apollo v3**.

If there are some other ways to resolve the issue, you are welcome to answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the @BoD answer in the [GitHub issue mentioned in the question](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/issues/2492#issuecomment-1139625549), the new way to take Android flavors into accounts is [`createAllAndroidVariantServices`](https://apollographql.github.io/apollo-kotlin/kdoc/apollo-gradle-plugin-external/com.apollographql.apollo3.gradle.api/-apollo-extension/create-all-android-variant-services.html), which basically specifies different sources for the different build-types. So, as documentation says, I have created `src/debug/graphql/$sourceFolder` with my debug-schema, and correspondingly `src/release/graphql/$sourceFolder` with the prod-schema. I have also added next config to my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
apollo {
    createAllAndroidVariantServices(".", "") {
        if (name.contains("staging")) {
            // add if you have staging build-variant, which uses the same scheme as prod
            srcDir(file("src/release/graphql/"))
        }

        packageName.set("com.example.myapp")
    }
}
```